# Why aren't my queued tasks being handled by all threads in the threadpool?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, threadpool

I wrote a simple Java program to help play with Threads and Thread pools to complete certain tasks. In my program, there are objects of class `TheObject` which have to have some kind of processing done to them (in this case, just a sleep delay and printing out their fields).

`TheObject` objects are placed in a queue, from which `WorkerThread`s draw them and process them.

I created a `Manager` class that initializes the `TheObjects`s and the `WorkerThread`s. I'm getting strange output when I run it; Instead of the Threads switching off the work, one thread is handling everything! Why is this happening? How do I get the threads to share the workload?

This is the **output**:

```
--------------------------------------------
alfred   a   0
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
bob   b   1
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
carl   c   2
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
dave   d   3
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
earl   e   4
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
fred   f   5
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
greg   g   6
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
harry   h   7
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
izzie   i   8
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
jim   j   9
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
kyle   k   0
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
Larry   L   1
Thread-1
--------------------------------------------
Michael   M   2
Thread-1
--------------------------------------------
Ned   N   3
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
Olaf   O   4
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
Peter   P   5
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
Quincy   Q   6
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
Raphael   R   7
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
Sam   S   8
Thread-0
--------------------------------------------
Trixie   T   9
Thread-0
```

---

The Code:

Classes:

- Manager
- TheObject
- TheObjectQueue
- WorkerThread

**Manager**

```
public class Manager {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TheObjectQueue queue = new TheObjectQueue();
        //Create Objects
        int numberOfInitialObjects = 10;
        String[] arrayOfNames = {"alfred", "bob", "carl", "dave", "earl", "fred", "greg", "harry", "izzie", "jim"};
        //char[] arrayOfChars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
        //int[] arrayOfNums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInitialObjects; i++){
                TheObject anObject = new TheObject(arrayOfNames[i], arrayOfNames[i].charAt(0), i);
                queue.addToQueue(anObject);

        }

        int numberOfThreads = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
            WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(queue);
            workerThread.start();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String[] arrayOfNames2 = {"kyle", "Larry", "Michael", "Ned", "Olaf", "Peter", "Quincy", "Raphael", "Sam", "Trixie"};
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInitialObjects; i++){
            TheObject anObject = new TheObject(arrayOfNames2[i], arrayOfNames2[i].charAt(0), i);
            queue.addToQueue(anObject);
        }

    }
}
```

**TheObject**

```
public class TheObject {
    private String someName;
    private char someChar;
    private int someNum;

    public TheObject(String someName, char someChar, int someNum) {
        super();
        this.someName = someName;
        this.someChar = someChar;
        this.someNum = someNum;
    }

    public String getSomeName() {
        return someName;
    }
    public char getSomeChar() {
        return someChar;
    }
    public int getSomeNum() {
        return someNum;
    }
}
```

**TheObjectQueue**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TheObjectQueue {

    private LinkedList<TheObject> objectQueue = null;

    public TheObjectQueue(){
        objectQueue = new LinkedList<TheObject>();
    }
    public LinkedList<TheObject> getQueue(){
        return objectQueue;
    }
    public void addToQueue(TheObject obj){
        synchronized (this) {
            objectQueue.addFirst(obj);
            this.notify();
        }

    }
    public TheObject removeFromQueue(){
        synchronized (this) {
            TheObject obj = objectQueue.removeLast();
            return obj;
        } 
    }
    public int getSize(){
        return objectQueue.size();
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return objectQueue.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**WorkerThread**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class WorkerThread extends Thread{
    private TheObjectQueue queue;

    public WorkerThread(TheObjectQueue queue){
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    public void process(TheObject obj){
        //Stall for a random amount of time
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(3)*1000;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(randomInt);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Begin Printing
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print(obj.getSomeName());
        System.out.print("   ");
        System.out.print(obj.getSomeChar());
        System.out.print("   ");
        System.out.println(obj.getSomeNum());
        System.out.println(this.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            synchronized (queue) {
                while(queue.isEmpty()){
                    try {
                        queue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                TheObject objToDealWith = queue.removeFromQueue();
                process(objToDealWith);
                super.run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use an ExecutorService?

Comment: @Jarrod I don't see how this is a duplicate. Even if the tools exist to do this differently, the question isn't about their use. I'm re-opening.

Comment: <s>One possible reason for this behavior is `isEmpty()` being not synchronized, so all other worker threads, except `thread-0` always see queue as empty.</s> Oops, no, you call `isEmpty` holding lock on `queue`, so `isEmpty()` should works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synchronization over the (shared) queue in WorkerThread.run only allows a single thread to process a task at a time - the effect is effectively a one-worker pool! In this case, Thread 0 "wins" most of the time on obtaining the lock; synchronized lock acquisition is [*not* guaranteed to be fair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101371/synchronized-lock-grant-order-when-multiple-thread-ask-for-it).

A simple fix is to fetch the task from the queue, using the required thread-safe construct, and then process the task *outside* of the synchronized section. This allows the workers to process the tasks, which are assumed to be independent, concurrently.

```
// e.g.
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        TheObject objToDealWith; 
        synchronized (queue) {
            // Only synchronized on queue when fetching task
            objToDealWith = getTask(queue);
        }

        // Process task; independent of queue
        process(objToDealWith);
    }
}
```

Since one of the threads will be busy processing a task, while the other is obtaining (or has obtained) a lock on the queue, the work distribution will "be fair".

Answer (score -1):

Why so difficult?
Just use the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) provided by java.

If you write it by hand you are doing it wrong.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      configure here how many threads and other properties, the queue here is actually build in.
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        String[] arrayOfNames = { "alfred", "bob", "carl", "dave", "earl",
                "fred", "greg", "harry", "izzie", "jim" };
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
            TheObject anObject = new TheObject(arrayOfNames[i], arrayOfNames[i].charAt(0), i);
            MyRunnable runnalbe = new MyRunnable(anObject);
            executor.execute(runnalbe);
        }
        executor.shutdown()
    }

    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        final TheObject anObject;

        MyRunnable(TheObject theObject) {
            this.anObject = theObject;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO do work with anObject
        }

    }

    static class TheObject {
        private String someName;
        private char someChar;
        private int someNum;

        public TheObject(String someName, char someChar, int someNum) {
            this.someName = someName;
            this.someChar = someChar;
            this.someNum = someNum;
        }

        public String getSomeName() {
            return someName;
        }

        public char getSomeChar() {
            return someChar;
        }

        public int getSomeNum() {
            return someNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the question are you answering?

Comment: At most, this should be a comment.

Comment: all. Reinventing a Queue? No way. Reinventing an ExecutorService/ThreadPool? No. Reinventing the Wheel? No. Reinventing a ThreadFactory? No. So my answer is: use the tools that are provided by java. => If you use these Classes there would be no problem.

Comment: Then show us how you would use `ExecutorService` to solve OP's problems. Link only answers are [extremely _poor_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @Zarathustra As the code stands and with including `user2864740`'s answer, is there anything missing that would be included if using `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @Imray I updated my answer and added some example code.

Comment: One important reason for OP's described behavior is the code in the `run()` method and how the `TheObjectQueue` is used. You haven't addressed the problem.

Comment: @Zarathustra Thanks. So I'm guessing that when `executor.execute(runnalbe);` is called, the object is added to some sort of `Queue` structure... and Executor takes care of the handling. Right?

Comment: @Imray right, you can even decide what for a queue to use, there are many factory methods from the `Executors` class.